4G router static routing without gateway
I have one server machine (M0) that has 2 ethernet ports. This machine is only enabled to configure 1 gateway. Lets say:
eth0 - 192.168.1.1, gateway: 192.168.1.100
eth1 - 192.168.2.1

I am connecting this machine to two 4g routers on each eth0 and eth1 - router0 and router1.
And I have another 2 remote machines (M1 and M2) to access these 2 ports separately.
On the router0, I configured the LAN to be 192.168.1.100. Port mapping of router0 as below:
Service Port: 8080
Internal Address: 192.168.1.1
Internal Port: 8080

This works well for the first remote machine M1. I was able to access M0's eth0 fine.
Router1's LAN IP is 192.168.2.100. And its port map as follows:
Service Port: 8080
Internal Address: 192.168.2.1
Internal Port: 8080

But since eth1 does not have gateway, I cannot setup the link like this. I was told I should do a "static route", I tried something but it does not work. Appreciate if anyone could give me some pointers or guidance to setup a static route between M0's eth1 and M2.
Here is my M0's route table:
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.100  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1

I tried:
ip route change 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.2.100 dev eth1

And table becomes:
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.1.100  0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.1.0    *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.2.0    192.168.2.100  255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth1

I can ping from M0 to 192.168.2.100 but I cannot access network from M2.

The route you had (for 192.168.2.0/24) was already a static route. What you did was changing a direct route into an indirect route, which makes no sense because:

You do not need an indirect route (i.e. making use of a gateway) for access to the LAN hosts, at least not in normal circumstances

The destination hosts in concern here are not even the LAN hosts, AFAICT


Unless the host(s) that would access "router1->M0" (e.g., M2) would always have the same IP (from the POV of router1), and it would never access router0->M0 with that IP, you pretty much NEED a default route with the gateway 192.168.2.100.
Suppose the OS of M0 is Linux, what you need to do would be to have the two default routes with different gateway placed in different route table, and leverage policy routing to have the host look up the appropriate route table based on certain condition(s), such as the replying source address (i.e., 192.168.1.1 or 192.168.2.1) or fwmark (which you can set for the replies by leveraging something called connmark). Check out ip-rule(8) for mor details.
If M2 does have a fixed IP, say x.y.z.w, then the static route you need would be x.y.z.w via 192.168.2.100. A default route is really a way to say "use this route for any destination that is not covered by the non-default routes I have", which is why you need it when the IP of "M2(s)" is "indeterministic".
Yet another way to "solve" this would be setting up a source NAT on router1 for its WAN, but this is only possible if the router is "really configurable" (like, if it is a "Linux router"). With this approach you don't need to mess with routing in M0, since all the traffics that get to it via router1 would "look" originated from router1 (i.e., their source IP would always be 192.168.2.100).

Thanks. So i use static routes and deleted all the gateways and it works.
